# Difference between macros and Functions in C language

Tags: c, function, macros

I'm new to C language. When I'm learning C language I learn something called macros. As I understood macros are like a functions in JavaScript that we can call when we needed. But then I learn that after compiling the program all the places that i have called to macros are replaced by the definition of the macro. So I'm confusing what is the difference between macro and a function in C language.

Also I wanna know whether I can write multi line macros in my code and if it is possible how it will be replaced when the code compiled.

As a example assume that I wanna macro to `find the maximum value among two numbers`.

Is it a good practice to write that process as a macro rather than write is as a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything stands - *don't use macro*. A better alternative `inline` the function - it would achieve the same efficiency you expect. But for fun, I worked a bit to use gcc [`statement expressions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that means a non-portable gcc centric solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SUM(X)                           \
    ({  long s = 0;                      \
        long x = (X) > 0 ? (X) : (-(X)); \
        while(x) {                       \
            s += x % 10;                 \
            x /= 10;                     \
        }                                \
        s;                               \
    })
int main(void) {
    printf("%ld\n",SUM(13423) );
    return 0;
}
```

This solution begs for a function. Using statement expression to have that `return` something feature inside macro. Well I said, go for inline function. That would serve the purpose much cleaner way.

Answer (score -1):

Using macros is sometimes dangourous:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html#Macro-Pitfalls
you can read on the dangers of using it here..

but, for your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUM(X, Y) (X + Y)
void main() {
    printf("the sum of 3,4 is : %d\n", SUM(3,4));
}
```

will output:

```
the sum of 3,4 is : 7
```

Comment: Better to enclose your parameters in parenthesis `#define SUM(X, Y) ((X) + (Y))` [Operator Precedence Problems:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Operator-Precedence-Problems.html#Operator-Precedence-Problems) `:)`

Comment: I don't see how that can effect the outcome here, but in general i accept this comment. again I personally think it is a bad isea to use macros in this fashion (inline are preferabble, at least from my viewpoint) debugging these are difficult... thanks

Comment: This doesn’t give the sum of the digits of ONE number.

Comment: @Fredrik - you are correct - i misunderstood the question. as far as i'm concerened coderredoc answer is the correct one..